# How can I use Scipy to do a memory efficient distance transform operation?

Tags: python, memory, numpy, scipy

I am working on a project in Python using GDAL to work on GIS rasters. These rasters or images can get rather large so I usually use memory mapping in Numpy to load them. Currently I want to do a distance transform operation on a memory mapped Numpy array. I was trying to use Scipy's [distance_transform_edt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.distance_transform_edt.html) function, however, this function returns a copy of the result in memory and I end up getting a memory error.

```
561, in distance_transform_dataset
    dest_array = ndimage.distance_transform_edt(source_array) * pixel_size
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/ndimage/morphology.py", line 2173,   
    in distance_transform_edt
input = numpy.atleast_1d(numpy.where(input, 1, 0).astype(numpy.int8))
MemoryError
None
```

A lot of times functions like this will have an 'out' parameter to write the result to. This function does not, so I can't write to a memory mapped numpy array.

Any ideas on how to do a memory efficient distance transform calculation on a large numpy array would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: do several operations on smaller slices or modify the code to do operations inplace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What version of Scipy are you using? In the version I'm running (0.12.0), there is no `out` parameter because there are two output parameters: `distances` and `indices`, which can both be used for output. If these are provided and are instances of ndarray or a subclass, scipy will do the transform in place with them. From the documentation:

> distance : ndarray, optional
>
> Used for output of distance array, must be of type float64.
>
> indices : ndarray, optional
>
> Used for output of indices, must be of type int32.

Note that there is a typo in the documentation, at least in 0.12.0: `distance` should be `distances`.

Unfortunately, this doesn't appear to be your actual problem. Your actual problem appears to occur in distance_transform_edt's conversion of `input` to binary, which looks like it makes a copy of `input`... just how large is your input?

It may be worth writing your own distance_transform_edt version based off of the scipy version. It's only around 50 lines, and most of those are dealing with various input/output types.